# Install GRUB on flash drive for dual boot [W10 + Arch Linux]

Tags: arch-linux, dual-boot

I have my laptop PC installed with Windows 10 (SSD drive) and Arch Linux (Hard Drive). I've tried to dual boot but the process was a pain: Windows 10 couldn't "suspend" or "hibernate", so I ended up reinstalling the boot partition for Windows.

How do I install `grub`, or is it possible to install `grub` on a flash drive so I can choose which Operating System to boot?

Comment: Are you using MBR first sector or grub.efi ?

Comment: At this point ... I think... neither.
Windows 10 must be installed on a GPT partition style